# understanding dangling pointer when implicit copy constructor is called

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, dangling-pointer

I am trying to demonstrate concept of **dangling pointer** and so writing a program on it.

Suppose if u have **pointer** as a **class variable** and u don't write ur own copy constructor then it can lead to concept of dangling pointer.

**Implicit copy constructor** does a member wise copy of elements(**shallow copy**).So if one object goes out of scope it leads to problem of dangling pointer.

So is this program which i wrote to demonstrate dangling pointer correct?
When i compiled it on ideone.com and it gave a runtime error.

```
#include"iostream"
using namespace std;
#include<string.h>

class cString
{
 int mlen;char* mbuff;   //**pointer** is a member of class

 public:
    cString(char *buff)  //copy buff in mbuff
    {
     mlen=strlen(buff);
     mbuff=new char[mlen+1];
     strcpy(mbuff,buff);
    }
    void display()       //display mbuff
    {
     cout<<mbuff;
    }

    ~cString()
    {
     cout<<"Destructor invoked";
     delete[] mbuff;               //free memory pointed by mbuff
    }
};

int main()
{
 cString s1("Hey");
  {
  cString s2(s1);            //call default copy constructor(shallow copy)
  s2.display();      
  }                   //destructor for object s2 is called here as s2 goes out of scope
 s1.display();               //object s1.display() should be unable to display hey

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am asking if my program to demonstrate dangling pointer correct?

Comment: _"I am asking if my program to demonstrate dangling pointer correct?"_ So give a better answer as one of those provided there.

Comment: Take a look at my program plz...

Comment: There's nothing wrong with duplicate questions in 1st place. You would have wanted, to provide an answer along with your question when posting. Though I would have marked the dupe. The main intention of duplicates, is to consolidate the Q&A structure of SO, and help future researchers on the topic.

Comment: yes i appreciate that...but is my program correct?

Comment: _"but is my program correct "_ No, it just seems to expose undefined behavior. You can't rely on kinda _chrashes_ portably.